# emacs: load html-mode in template directory

Tags: emacs

I use php mode for .php files, but codeigniter uses .php for the template files which are mostly html, so I would like to use html-mode for those files.

Is there a way to say in the .emacs file "If the file path contains '/views/' use html-mode"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `html-mode` for all files under a directory named `views` and its sub-directories, you can add the following line *at the end of `.emacs`*:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("/views/" . html-mode))
```

Note that `("/views/" . html-mode)` should appear before an entry for `.php` files when you check the value of `auto-mode-alist` by <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>auto-mode-alist</kbd>.

Similarly, the following line at the end of `.emacs` will make Emacs choose `html-mode` for all `.php` files under a directory named `views` and its sub-directories:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("/views/.*\\.php\\'" . html-mode))
```

---

From `auto-mode-alist`'s documentation:

> **`auto-mode-alist`**
>
> Alist of filename patterns vs corresponding major mode functions. Each element looks like (REGEXP . FUNCTION) or (REGEXP FUNCTION NON-NIL). ... Visiting a file whose name matches REGEXP specifies FUNCTION as the mode function to use.  FUNCTION will be called, unless it is nil.